# Javascript/jQuery/Datatables sum values triggered by checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I can't figure out how to correct my javascript to make it work correctly. My goal is to have a sum of values in the table footer, picking up only checked rows. Single rows selection works fine, but using the thead checkbox to add 'checked' property to every row displayed it doesn't trigger the action. Here is my code:

Javascript

```
 //check all
    $("#check-all").click(function () {
        $(".data-check").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    $('#sumchecked').html('KG selezione: ');

    $('#inventario', 'thead').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
        var totalSUM = 0;
        $('#sumchecked').html('KG selezione: ' +totalSUM.toFixed(3));

        $('tr:has(:checked)').each(function () {
            var getValue = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(3)").html().replace(",", "."));
            totalSUM += getValue;

            $('#sumchecked').html('KG selezione: ' +totalSUM.toFixed(3));

        });
    });
```

HTML Markup

```
<table id="inventario" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th><input type="checkbox" id="check-all"></th>
                 <th>N° Collo</th>
                 <th>Ordine</th>
                 <th>KG</th>
                 <th>Operatore</th>
                 <th><span style="font-size:1.5em;" title="Cimosa" class="icon-scissors-cutting-by-broken-line"></span></th>
                 <th><span style="font-size:1.5em;" title="Specola" class="icon-silk"></span></th>
                 <th>Falli</th>
                 <th>Note</th>
                 <th>Data Produzione</th>
                 <th>Stato</th>
                 <th>Consegna</th>
                 <th>Azioni</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th><div id="sumchecked"></div></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Php controller in Codeigniter, ajax_list function used to generate table data

```
 public function ajax_list()
{
    $list = $this->packing->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $pezza) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = '<input type="checkbox" class="data-check" value="'.$pezza->n_pezza.'">';
        $row[] = $pezza->n_pezza;
        $row[] = $pezza->ID_ordine;
        $row[] = number_format($pezza->kg_pezza,3,",",".");
        $row[] = $pezza->nome_operatore;
        if($pezza->selvedge == '1'){
            $row[] = '<span style="font-size:1.5em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>';
        }else{
            $row[] = '';
        }
        if($pezza->specola == '1'){
            $row[] = '<span style="font-size:1.5em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>';
        }else{
            $row[] = '';
        }
        $row[] = $pezza->falli;
        $row[] = $pezza->note;
        $row[] = $this->conversione1($pezza->data);
        if ($pezza->stato == '1'){
            $row[] = '<span style="font-size:1.5em;" title="Consegnata"class="icon-logistics-delivery-truck-in-movement"></span>';
            $row[] = $this->conversione2($pezza->data_consegna);
        }else{
            $row[] = '<span style="font-size:1.5em;" title="Magazzino" class="icon-warehouse"></span>';
            $row[] = '';
        }

        $row[] = '<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" style="width:136px">
                  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Modifica" onclick="modifica_pezza('."'".$pezza->n_pezza."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Info Filati" onclick="info_pezza('."'".$pezza->n_pezza."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Cancella" onclick="cancella_pezza('."'".$pezza->n_pezza."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                  </div>';

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->packing->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->packing->count_filtered(),
                    "data" => $data,
            );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

This is my output if I check the first checkbox in thead
[output sum checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5rXn.png)
Suggestions?
Thanks to everyone who will take some time to read and solve my problem.
Andy

Comment: rest of the HTML... and the current output please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to generate HTML code in `#sumchecked` on server side and put the attribute `visibility: hidden` to it. When you select a row, you do not need to run through all the selected rows every time. To minimize DOM traversing, it is better to request the current value of the total sum, and then add / subtract the price of the selected item to / from it. To get the sum of all selected items, simply insert in `#checked-prices-total-sum` the value from `#totalkg`.

For example, I took a 3 rows from your HTML table only with price columns and changed the code of your script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#check-all").click(function() {
        var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
        $(".data-check").prop('checked', isChecked);
        var $sumchecked = $('#sumchecked');
        var $totalSum = $('#checked-prices-total-sum');

        if (isChecked) {
            $totalSum.html($('#totalkg').html());
            $sumchecked.css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else {
            $totalSum.html(0);
            $sumchecked.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });

    $('#inventario-data').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
        var $sumchecked = $('#sumchecked');
        var $totalSum = $('#checked-prices-total-sum');
        var totalSumValue = parseFloat($totalSum.html());
        var price = parseFloat($(this).parent().next().next().html().replace(",", "."));

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            totalSumValue += price;
        } else {
            totalSumValue -= price;
        }

        $totalSum.html(totalSumValue.toFixed(3));
        totalSumValue > 0 ? $sumchecked.css('visibility', 'visible') : $sumchecked.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table id="inventario" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="check-all"></th>
        <th>N° Collo</th>
        <th>Ordine</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="inventario-data">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="data-check"></td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>10,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-rowid="2">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="data-check"></td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>30,400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-rowid="3">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="data-check"></td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>50,600</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><div id="sumchecked" style="visibility: hidden;">KG selezione: <span id="checked-prices-total-sum">0</span></div></th>
        <th>Tot. KG <span id="totalkg">91,200</span></th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Excellent Idea! I'm gonna test it as soon as I fix my vpn, but I'm sure it's ok for me. I think there are some issues with the parseFloat values cause in italian notation "," stands for ".", anyway it's not a price column but a weight column in kilograms. Thanks a lot for your hint, it really saved the day for me :-)

Comment: I checked everything today and it works like a charm. I just edited couple of Javascript lines where I was giving Datatables API coordinates to place total kg sum. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndyBiancoblu You're welcome! I’m glad I could help.